# How come my array is null when writing data to it?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out why my program says my array is null and cannot be written to. I created an Element class to determine what elements would be in the array, so the array is type `Element[]`. The array takes in data from a file and then is supposed to add it to the array. The program seems to read the data from the file but it will not add it to the array.

```
class Array extends Element
{

    //Global Variables
    public static Element[] array;

    //Max number of entries
    private int numMax;
    public int numElements;

    //Constructors
    public Array()
    {

    }

    public Array(int numMax)
    {
        //Instantiate the array
        array = new Element[numMax];
        numElements = 0;
    }
```

This is a function to insert the data into the array:

```
public void insertValue(String firstName, String lastName,
            String company, String address, String city, String state,
            String county, String phone, int zip, long key, int rowNum)
    {
        try
        {

        //Add elements to array
        System.out.println(numElements);
        array[numElements].setFirstName(firstName);
        array[numElements].setLastName(lastName);
        array[numElements].setCompany(company);
        array[numElements].setAddress(address);
        array[numElements].setCity(city);
        array[numElements].setState(state);
        array[numElements].setCounty(county);
        array[numElements].setPhone(phone);
        array[numElements].setZip(zip);
        array[numElements].setKey(key);
        array[numElements].setRowNum(rowNum);

        //Increment number of elements in the array
        numElements++;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my input function:

```
public static void readInputFile()
    {
        //Create a new instance of the array class so that the array can be
        //written to without creating a new array for either merge or insert
        //sort
        Array arr = new Array(1000010);

        Element[] array = arr.getArray();

        try
        {
            fileRead = new FileReader(fileLocation);
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));

            //Allows the first line of the file that includes the titles to 
            //not be added to the array
            String line = br.readLine();

             //Counter for iterating through array
                int elemCntr = 0;
            while (elemCntr != 10)
            {
                //Variables
                String lineline = br.readLine();



                //This will split the line into sections based on the 
                //placement of comas: split data into sections
                String[] readLine = lineline.split(",");
                firstName = readLine[0];
                lastName = readLine[1];
                company = readLine[2];
                address = readLine[3];
                city = readLine[4];
                county = readLine[5];
                state = readLine[6];
                zip = Integer.parseInt(readLine[7]);
                phone = readLine[8];
                key = Long.parseLong(readLine[9]);
                rowNum = arr.numElements + 1;

                //Insert data into array
                arr.insertValue(firstName, lastName, company, address, city,
                        state, county, phone, zip, key, rowNum);
             }
         } catch (Exception e){
          // do something
         }
 }
```

Can you identify any problems, please?

Comment: Please format your code properly. And at what line are you getting the error (and what error)?

Comment: exceptions have 4 bits of info in them: Type, message, trace, and cause. You're tossing 3 of the 4 things. Stop doing this; do not write catch blocks at all if you don't actually have a good plan to deal with it. Just add 'throws X' to the method's signature if you must. That'll help you solve this problem, too.

Comment: You have only created the array but havent initialized the `Element` instance. The first thing you have to do before setting properties is to create an Element object `array[numElements] = new Element();` (assuming there is a default constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Try with using **ArrayList**

You are trying to make dynamic array of class Element which is possible.But it is bad practice as u have to write initialization statement for every element.Initialization are meant to be done in constructors.

- Declaration: `Element element[] = new Element[5];`
- Initialization: `element[0] = new Element();`

;
It is possible to make dynamic arrays of int , string etc easily then of Class.

PS: Try giving different names you are having **Arrays** as class and **arrays** as variable also.

Answer (score 0):

your code is n't clear, but if you call readInputFile method first, it will instantiate array and then when you call insertValue method it should work properly, because array is static.